# in kedro / pyspark how to use MemoryDataset

Tags: python, pyspark, kedro

I am trying to use a MemoryDataset with kedro, in order to not save the intermeiate result to disk.

```
# nodes.py
def preprocess_format_tracksessions(tracksess: DataFrame, userid_profiles:pd.DataFrame , parameters: Dict) -> MemoryDataset:
```

In the pipeline I am defining the node output and inputs:

```
# pipeline.py
def create_pipeline(**kwargs) -> Pipeline:
    return pipeline([ 
        node( 
                func=preprocess_format_tracksessions,
                inputs= ["track_sessions", "userid_profiles", "parameters"],
                outputs="ts_formatted",
                name="preprocess_format_tracksessions",
            ),
        node( 
                func=process_tracksessions,
                inputs= ["ts_formatted", "parameters"],
                outputs="results_summary",
                name="process_format_tracksessions",
            ),            
    ])
```

And in the catalog I am defining

```
ts_formatted:
  type: MemoryDataSet
```

But every time I get this error, surely because of my misunderstanding on how to proceed. Any help much appreciated:

```
DatasetError: Failed while saving data to data set MemoryDataset().
It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation.
SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see
SPARK-5063.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @gaut you may need to add this to your YAML definition:

```yaml
ts_formatted:
  type: MemoryDataSet
  copy_mode: assign
```

For normal, not explicitly defined `MemoryDataSets` Kedro will infer this copy mode like so:

https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/_modules/kedro/io/memory_dataset.html#MemoryDataset.__init__